# I am not able checkin/checkout the files in sub folders in the document library using client object model. Below is the code I am using

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, client-object-model

```
public void CheckOut()// CHECK OUT FUNCTION 
{
try
{
    string siteurl = "";
    string filePath = "";

    ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteurl);
    context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    Web web = context.Web;
    File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath);

    file.CheckOut();
    context.Load(web);
    context.Load(file);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    if (file.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None)
    {
        file.CheckOut();
    }
    context.Load(file);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
}
```

Comment: are u getting the file ?

Comment: I am not getting files.

Comment: try these links http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658788.aspx http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/11/01/using-the-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-part-6.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below two ways code snippet for your requirement. Enhance it for your needs.

```
private static void FolderCheckOut(string SiteUrl, string FolderPath)
{
    try
    {
        using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(SiteUrl))
        {
            Web oWeb = ctx.Web;
            ctx.Load(oWeb);
            List lib = oWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");
            ctx.Load(lib.RootFolder);

            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            Folder oFolder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(lib.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + FolderPath);
            FileCollection files = oFolder.Files;
            ctx.Load(files);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (File fi in files)
            {
                ctx.Load(fi);
                if (fi.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None)
                {
                    fi.CheckOut();
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

OR

```
private static void FolderCheckOut(string SiteUrl, string FolderPath)
{
    try
    {
        using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(SiteUrl))
        {
            Web oWeb = ctx.Web;
            ctx.Load(oWeb);
            List lib = oWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");
            ctx.Load(lib.RootFolder);

            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            //CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>";
            query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/sites/Company/Shared Documents/Folder1/";
            ListItemCollection listItems = lib.GetItems(query);
            ctx.Load(listItems);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem li in listItems)
            {
                ctx.Load(li, l => l.File);
                File fi = li.File;
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                if (fi.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None)
                {
                    fi.CheckOut();
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If you are going for Option 2 make sure that FolderServerRelativeUrl is set correctly. This should be set such that everything is included after www.somesite.com/ in case of external sites. In case of internal sites URL after servername:port/ needs to included. This will resolve the issue related to.

> Value does not fall within the expected range